# How to process a dataframe of pandas that contain long series in one of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Consider the following minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
        'foo': [pd.Series(np.random.randn(3)*2) for x in xrange(8)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'foo'])
```

When rendering `df` in `iPython` I get something like:

```
    year    foo
0   2010    0 1.936300 1 0.460437 2 1.895832 dtyp...
1   2011    0 -1.639541 1 -0.460803 2 0.196103 dtyp...
2   2012    0 1.868190 1 -0.571973 2 0.029239 dtyp...
3   2011    0 -1.034721 1 -1.268487 2 0.719374 dtyp...
4   2012    0 1.249795 1 3.279158 2 -3.221805 dtyp...
5   2010    0 3.175814 1 -3.441948 2 -3.710086 dtyp...
6   2011    0 1.237284 1 -2.225327 2 2.923511 dtyp...
7   2012    0 -1.306018 1 -0.804952 2 -0.861195 dtyp...
```

I would like to have the following:

```
    year    foo
0   2010    0 1.936300 
            1 0.460437 
            2 1.895832
1   2011    0 -1.639541
            1 -0.460803 
            2 0.196103 
2   2012    0 1.868190 
            1 -0.571973 
            2 0.029239 
3   2011    0 -1.034721 
            1 -1.268487 
            2 0.719374
```

In particular, each cell in the `foo` column should show all the values in the corresponding series (and omit the `dtype` part).

Another desired view, and it might be just as useful, is to split the series that constitute `foo`. In other words, in the above example, have six columns (instead of one for `foo`) that will hold the indices and values of the series.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?:

```
s = df['foo'].apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel()
s.name = 'foo'
del df['foo']
df = df.join(s)
df
```